# PayPal Express Checkout Instant Update not updating shipping

Tags: php, paypal

I am using the Paypal Express Checkout and everything working good except the shipping carrier not being updated when the Callback is being called.

I can verify the callback is being called (call is logged).
When Paypal call the callback URL with the customer shipping country I return the following values.

```
METHOD=CallbackResponse&OFFERINSURANCEOPTION=false&CURRENCYCODE=USD&TOKEN=EC-5Fsdf5523823&LOCALECODE=en_US&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=USPS&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL0=First+Class+%283-7+Days%29&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0=0.00&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=true&L_TAXAMT0=0.00&L_INSURANCEAMOUNT0=0.00&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME1=USPS&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL1=Priority+%282-3+Days%29&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT1=7.95&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT1=false&L_TAXAMT1=0.00&L_INSURANCEAMOUNT1=0.00&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME2=UPS&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL2=Next+Day+Air&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT2=39.95&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT2=false&L_TAXAMT2=0.00&L_INSURANCEAMOUNT2=0.00
```

The Callback message is being echo'd through PHP (I even tried save this as a txt file and point the callback URL to this file), even then Paypal doesn't update the Shipping Method.

I also changed CALLBACKTIMEOUT to 6 seconds but it doesn't matter. I am using HTTPS and also tried it with normal HTTP.

I am testing this in sandbox mode.

Anyone could help me out? I am really stuck here and I have been searching for similar problems but couldn't find any.

For your information I followed this Paypal guide : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPInstantUpdateAPI/

I also checked if I am returning all the required fields as described here :
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/Callback_API_Operation_NVP/

I hope someone can help me out, thanks in advance!

---

UPDATE

I try the NO SHIPPING OPTION

```
METHOD=CallbackResponse&NO_SHIPPING_OPTION_DETAILS=1&CALLBACKVERSION=95.0
```

Paypal responds with 'doesnot ship to this location. Please use a different address.'
So the response url is working, the problem is when responding with other shipping options.

---

Regards,
Kuroudu

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problems as you, but then I tried the example code from the PayPal Instant Update integration guide and added it as a text file on my server:

```
METHOD=CallbackResponse&OFFERINSURANCEOPTION=true&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=UPS+Air&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL0=UPS+Next+Day+Air+Freight&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0=20.00&L_TAXAMT0=2.20&L_INSURANCEAMOUNT0=1.51&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=false&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME1=UPS+Expedited&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL1=UPS+Express+2+Days&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT1=10.00&L_TAXAMT1=2.00&L_INSURANCEAMOUNT1=1.35&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT1=true&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME2=UPS+Ground&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL2=UPS+Ground+2+to+7+Days&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT2=5.99&L_TAXAMT2=1.99&L_INSURANCEAMOUNT2=1.28&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT2=false
```

This at least gave me a CallbackResponse that finally worked which I then could update with programming to make it function the rest of the way.  Spent many hours ripping my hair out.  As PayPal doesn't really provide any means of debugging the CallbackResponses, I was happy to have a functioning starting point.

Hopefully this helps to point others in the right direction.